# View Paid Sorting

Tags: views

I wanted to do something like following scenario.

So for example I have a view of content type 'mycontent'.

Bob wants to be on the top and he is paying me money for it. Is there any way I can show paid node first in the View Display ? Based on what they pay.

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S : I am using Drupal 7. And I already have 1000 nodes of the content type.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a field on the node to track how much has been paid. Use [hook_field_access()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_access/7) or [field_permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) to make this field so that it can't be modified by the user. Use [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) or custom code to set this field with the amount paid when the node is paid for. Then order your view by this field descending.